# Is $H(x − ct)$ a weak solution of the wave equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, wave-equation

This problem is from the book by Strauss (1), §12.1, Exercise 5 p. 337.

> 5. Verify, directly from the definition of a distribution, that the discontinuous function $u(x, t) = H(x − ct)$ is a weak solution of the wave
>      equation.

A function is called a weak solution of the wave equation $u_{tt}=c^2 u_{xx}$ if $\iint _{\mathbb R^2}u(x,t) (\phi_{tt}-c^2 \phi_{xx})dxdt=0$ for every $C^\infty$ function with compact support $\phi$.

I tried that $$
\begin{aligned}
\iint _{\mathbb R^2}u(x,t) (\phi_{tt}-c^2 \phi_{xx})dxdt &=\iint_{x>ct} (\phi_{tt}-c^2\phi_{xx})dxdt \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{x/c}\phi_{tt}dtdx - c^2 \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{ct}^{\infty}\phi_{xx}dxdt \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi_t(x,x/c)dx+c^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi_x(ct,t)dt
\end{aligned}
$$

but I don't know how to proceed.
Does anyone have an idea?

---

(1) W.A. Strauss, *Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction*, 2nd ed., John Wiley & Sons, 2008.

Comment: Why is the inner integral over $\mathbb R^2$ and not $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @rubik That's not the inner integral, but just the double integral for all plane.

Comment: I see. Isn't it better to use $\iint$ then? I find the current form a bit confusing, even if the would-be-outer doesn't have bounds.

Comment: Okay, I edited it. Thanks.

Comment: Potentially, using integration by parts or a Green's Identity could simplify this, keeping in mind that $H^\prime(x) = \delta(x)$.

Comment: OK, I solved it. thanks!

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer? It helps for people who may search for this problem in the future.

Comment: Okay, I added. Could you check whether my solution is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, one can go back to the general definition of weak solutions, as proposed in OP (see [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3149626/418542) for complements). I will propose a solution which may be more in the spirit of the book (Example 10 p. 336). The derivatives of the discontinuous function $u(x,t) = H(x-ct)$ viewed as a distribution are
\begin{aligned}
u_x &= \delta(x-ct) , & u_t &= -c \delta(x-ct) ,\\
u_{xx} &= \delta'(x-ct) , & u_{tt} &= c^2 \delta'(x-ct) .
\end{aligned}
Hence, $u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx}$ and $u$ is called a “weak” solution of the wave
equation.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H(x-ct) (\phi_{tt}-c^2 \phi_{xx})dxdt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H(x-ct)\phi_{tt}dtdx-c^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H(x-ct)\phi_{xx}dxdt$

Now evaluate the inner integral of the first integral.
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H(x-ct)\phi_{tt}dt=H(x-ct)\phi_t|_{-\infty}^\infty +c\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-ct)\phi_{t}dt=c\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-ct)\phi_{t}dt=c[\delta(x-ct)\phi|_{-\infty}^{\infty}+c\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta'(x-ct)\phi dt]=c^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta'(x-ct)\phi dt$

Evaluating the inner integral of the second integral,
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H(x-ct)\phi_{xx}dx=H(x-ct)\phi_x|_{-\infty}^\infty -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-ct)\phi_{x}dx=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-ct)\phi_{t}dt=-\delta(x-ct)\phi|_{-\infty}^{\infty}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta'(x-ct)\phi dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta'(x-ct)\phi dt$

Therefore, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H(x-ct)\phi_{tt}dtdx-c^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H(x-ct)\phi_{xx}dxdt=c^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta'(x-ct)\phi dtdx-c^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta'(x-ct)\phi dxdt=0$

Am I right?

Comment: Why is $\phi_x$ compactly supported?