Is the Fourier series solution to the plucked string problem a weak solution to the wave equation?
I am looking at the Fourier series method applied to the plucked string problem:
\begin{align}
u_{tt} = u_{xx} & , \qquad 0 < x < \pi,  t>0 ;
\nonumber \\
u(0,t) = u(\pi,t) & , \qquad t>0 ;
\nonumber \\
u(x,0) = f(x) & , \qquad 0 < x < \pi ;
\nonumber \\
u(x,0) = g(x) = 0 & , \qquad 0 < x < \pi .
\end{align}
where $f(x) = ax, \; 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2} \pi , f(x) = a(\pi-x), \; \frac{1}{2} \pi \leq x \leq \pi , \quad  g(x) = 0$. The solution method is (i) write $u(x,t)= X(x)T(t)$ and plug it into $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$, to obtain: $X''(x)+ \lambda X(x)=0$ and $\ddot{T}(t)+ \lambda T(t)=0$ subject to $X(0)=X(\pi) = 0$. The boundary conditions require $\lambda = n^2 (n=1,2,3,\dots)$ and $X_n (x) = \sin nx$. The $T$ diff equation is solved by $T_n (t) = a_n \cos nt + b_n \sin nt$. By homogeneity $u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n \cos nt + b_n \sin nt) \sin nx$ (we are taking a limit here that $N \rightarrow \infty$). We then impose the initial conditions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to obtain the Fourier coefficients. The solution is:
\begin{align*}
u(x,t) & = \frac{4 a}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2} \cos ((2n+1)t) \sin ((2n-1)x)
\end{align*}
I have found various issues with this solution, outlined below. My question is can it be a weak solution? How would you establish it is a weak solution? I know of the method of checking for a weak solution here, but this method doesn't seem to apply in the present case.
If it's not a weak solution then why not?
Properties and issues with the solution:
A) The Fourier series can be rewritten as:
\begin{align*}
u(x,t) & = \frac{2a}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2} \sin ((2n+1) (x-t)) + \frac{2a}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2} \sin ((2n+1) (x+t))
\end{align*}
this is a superposition of triangle waves moving in opposite directions. Triangle waves are not differentiable at their extremal points. I will refer to these extremal points as the isolated points.
B) Differentiating term-by-term with respect to $t$ results in the following series, which I denote $Sq (x,t)$,
\begin{align*}
Sq (x,t) & = - \frac{2a}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} \cos ((2n+1) (x-t)) + \frac{2a}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} \cos ((2n+1) (x+t))
\end{align*}
which is a superposition of square waves moving in opposite directions. Each of these is not uniformly convergent because a series of continuous functions cannot converge uniformly to a discontinuous function (continuity is preserved by uniform convergence). Meaning that it is not ensured that it is legitimate to differentiate term-by-term. Despite this, it still seems you can differentiate the Fourier series $u (x,t)$ with respect to $t$ or $x$ term-by-term and the result (sum of two square waves) is equal to the function itself (sum of two triangles waves) differentiated. Albeit, except at isolated points where the triangle wave takes its extremal values.
An answer to this seeming conflict is that you can use the Dirichlet test to show that you have uniform convergence of $Sq (x,t)$ on intervals not containing the isolated points, and so it is legitimate to differentiate the Fourier series term-by-term on these intervals. I quickly illustrate this: consider $Sq (x,0) = \frac{4a}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} \sin ((2n-1) x)$ on the interval $[-\frac{\pi}{2} + \epsilon , \frac{\pi}{2} - \epsilon]$ where $0 < \epsilon < \frac{\pi}{2}$. Choose $f_n (x) = (-1)^{n-1} \cos ((2n-1) x)$ and $g_n (x) = \frac{1}{2n-1}$. The choice of $g_n(x)$ obviously satisfies the condition of the Dirichlet Test. So we just have to check that the partial sums of $f_n (x)$ are bounded uniformly in $n$ and $x$ on the interval $[-\frac{\pi}{2} + \epsilon , \frac{\pi}{2} - \epsilon]$. We have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=1}^n (-1)^{m-1} \cos ((2m-1) x) & = - \sum_{m=1}^n \sin ((2m-1) (x-\frac{\pi}{2}))
\nonumber \\
& = - \sum_{m=1}^n \dfrac{e^{i (2m-1)y} - e^{-i (2m-1)y}}{2i}  ,  \qquad  y=x-\frac{\pi}{2}
\nonumber \\
& = \dfrac{1+ (-1)^n \cos (2nx)}{2 \cos x}
\end{align*}
So
\begin{align*}
 \left| \sum_{m=1}^n (-1)^{m-1} \cos ((2m-1) x) \right| & = \left| \dfrac{1+ (-1)^n \cos (2nx)}{2 \cos x} \right| \leq \dfrac{1}{\cos (\frac{\pi}{2} - \epsilon)}
\end{align*}
and hence the partial sums are uniformly bounded in $n$ and $x$ on the interval $[-\frac{\pi}{2} + \epsilon , \frac{\pi}{2} - \epsilon]$. Note the partial sums would not be bounded on the interval $[-\frac{\pi}{2} , \frac{\pi}{2}]$ and the Dirichlet test would fail. The same arguments easily applies to the intervals $[- \pi, -\frac{\pi}{2} - \epsilon]$ and $[\frac{\pi}{2} + \epsilon, \pi]$.Therefore it is legitimate to differentiate term-by-term on intervals that don't include the isolated points.
C) Differentiating the Fourier series $Sq(x,t)$ term-by-term w.r.t. $t$ results in the following Fourier series, which I denote $F (x,t)$,
\begin{align*}
F (x,t) = - \frac{2a}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \sin ((2n+1) (x-t)) - \frac{2a}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} \sin ((2n+1) (x+t))
\end{align*}
which is the superposition of two Fourier series for the $\pi$-antiperiodic delta functions: $-a \delta (x-t-\frac{\pi}{2}) - a \delta (x+t-\frac{\pi}{2})$. Indeed, for $x = \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ the sum $- \frac{2a}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \sin ((2n+1) x)$ diverges. This "infinity" was inevitable because of the kinks in $u(x,t)$.
To elucidate a further issue, consider the truncated version of $F(x,0)$ on the intervals $[-\frac{\pi}{2} + \epsilon , \frac{\pi}{2} - \epsilon]$, $[- \pi, -\frac{\pi}{2} - \epsilon]$, and $[\frac{\pi}{2} + \epsilon, \pi]$. This can be explicitly evaluated:
\begin{align*}
F_N (x,0) = - \frac{4a}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^n \sin ((2n+1) x) = - (-1)^N \frac{2a}{\pi} \dfrac{\sin (2Nx)}{2 \cos x}
\end{align*}
The function at the end exhibits rapid oscillations as $N$ increases, with peak and trough amplitudes having the lower bound:
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{2 \cos (\dfrac{\pi}{4N})}
\end{align*}
This lower limit corresponds to the height of the first peak on the interval $[0 , \frac{\pi}{2})$ at $x=\frac{\pi}{4n}$, with subsequent peaks and troughs exhibiting an increasing amplitude as $x$ increases. So the distance between consecutive peaks tends to zero as $N \rightarrow \infty$ while the amplitude remains non-zero and finite. This limit is undefined. In particular, you don't get pointwise or uniform convergence. So it fails the standard test that guarantees you can differentiate $Sq (x,0)$ term-by-term, and it fails it everywhere and not just at isolated points. In fact, the result of differentiating term-by-term is not equal to the function itself (sum of two square waves) differentiated. Therefore, it is evidently an illegitimate operation.
We can say we have convergence in the following sense: for any $f \in C^\infty$ we have $- a f(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^\pi - (-1)^N \frac{2a}{\pi} \frac{\sin (2Nx)}{2 \cos x} f(x) dx$. Heuristically, as $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}$ the integral $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}-\delta} - (-1)^N \frac{2a}{\pi} \frac{\sin (2Nx)}{2 \cos x} f(x) dx$ approaches zero because the function $\frac{\sin (2Nx)}{2 \cos x}$ oscillates more rapidly, and $f(x)$ is nearly constant over adjacent peaks.  Same argument for $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}+\delta}^\pi \cdots$. Lastly, $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}-\delta}^{\frac{\pi}{2}+\delta} \cdots f(x) dx$ is $= f(\frac{\pi}{2}) \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}-\delta}^{\frac{\pi}{2}+\delta} \cdots dx = -a f(\frac{\pi}{2})$.
As we can't differentiate $u(x,t)$ w.r.t to either $t$ or $x$ term-by-term twice anywhere, it means the solution method presented at the beginning is not legitimate.

Maybe this will help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221365/is-hx-%E2%88%92-ct-a-weak-solution-of-the-wave-equation

@MOMO If you took a triangle function $Tr (x-t)$ and differentiated it twice w.r.t. $x$ or $t$ it would give $\delta(x-t)$. So you could start with $\int \int \phi (x,y)[\delta(x-t)-\delta(x-t)]dxdt=0$ and integrate by parts to get $\int \int [\phi_{tt}-\phi_{xx}]Tr (x-t)=0$. Does the fact that it isn't legitimate to differentiate the Fourier series term-by-term twice add a further complication as it means you can't start with $\int \int \phi (x,y) [F(x-t)-F(x-t)]dxdt=0$ and then integrate by parts to get $\int \int [\phi_{tt} - \phi_{xx}]u(x-t)=0$.

Your solution represented as a Fourier series is indeed cannot be differentiated twice tern by term, but it is continuous and almost everywhere smooth, therefore it still has an integrable second derivatives. The general form of the solution is $F(x+t)+G(x-t)$ where $F,G$ are smooth outside the lines $x\pm t=\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi\cdot n$. You may be able to use this general form instead of your solution to show it is a weak solution.
